# Difference between forwarded_fetch_count and forwarded_record_count

Tags: sql-server-2019, tempdb

I have been scratching my head, re-reading MSFT help and I still cannot understand the difference between *forwarded_fetch_count* and *forwarded_record_count* in sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats and sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats. Let me illustrate my problem of understanding the views with example below.

I have run following queries:

```
;with heaps as ( 
select 
    DB_NAME(DB_ID()) dbname, object_name ( p.object_id ) objname, sum(row_count) row_count,
    DB_ID() database_id, p.object_id objectid
from 
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
    join sys.objects o on o.object_id = p.object_id 
WHERE 
    index_id = 0 and o.is_ms_shipped = 0 --and row_count > 0
    group by p.object_id ) 
select 
    h.*, 
    forwarded_fetch_count
from heaps h
    cross apply sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(database_id, objectid, 0, null) ps
    WHERE forwarded_fetch_count > 0 ORDER BY forwarded_fetch_count DESC¨
```

AND

```
SELECT page_count, OBJECT_NAME(ps.object_id)
,avg_record_size_in_bytes
,avg_page_space_used_in_percent
,forwarded_record_count 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id('your_db_name'), NULL,NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') AS ps
WHERE forwarded_record_count IS NOT NULL AND forwarded_record_count > 0
GO
```

Both queries have returned different list of tables in a single database which I am tuning. First query returned tables with ranging from 1000 up to 100 000 of forwarded fetches per table, second query returned anything from 10 - 60 000 forwarded record count for other set of tables.

As a duct-tape fix, I have rebuilt the tables in question. Yet, in performance monitor in Windows, I am still seeing plenty of Forwarded Records / sec (the chart spikes often up to 100). When running sp_blitzfirst @seconds = 30, I am alerted about lot of forwarded fetches / sec. Once the alert is general (meaning not related to any DB), other 9 alerts of the same statement mention: "Forwarded Fetches/Sec High: TempDB Object". And as per forwarded fetches count, there's ten or hundred-fold more forwarded fetches in TempDB then out of TempDB.

Last but not least, the ISV has implemented triggers heavily (which I relate to the TempDB forwarded fetches).

My questions:

- What is  the difference between the two columns in two views?
- When dealing with slow database due to forwarded records on a heap, which one shall I use? (I know MSFT's help mentions forwarded_record_count in dm_db_index_physical_stats related to heaps specifically, still not making it clearer for me).
- Can I identify what in TempDB is causing these forwarded fetches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **physical stats** view returns information about the physical structure of the index or table.

The *forwarded record count* shows how many rows in the heap have *forwarded records*. These are created when a heap row is **updated** to a size that no longer fits on the page. The row is **moved** to a different page with sufficient space and a forwarding **pointer** is left behind in the original row.

For a heap table with 123 such forwarded records, the *forwarded record count* will also be 123.

The **operational stats** view keeps count of operations on the heap (or index) from the point of view of the storage engine.

A *forwarded fetch* occurs when an execution plan needs a heap row that has been forwarded. It is incremented each time a forward pointer is followed to locate the data needed by the query or statement.

Fully scanning a heap table with 123 forwarded records would add 123 to the *forwarded fetch* count. Running that query 5 times would add 5 x 123 = 615 to the count.

A single query (and execution plan) that scans the heap more than once could also add multiples of 123 to the count, or any other number in case the heap is only partially scanned (perhaps because the query has a `TOP` clause).

The point is the *forwarded fetch count* is incremented whenever any user, any query, and any plan operator within an execution plan needs a row from the heap and finds it has been forwarded.

---

In other words, the *operational stats* give you cumulative metrics about how queries are accessing data. The *physical stats* tell you about the physical state of the heap at a particular moment in time.

If you're interested in query performance, you'll most likely be paying attention to the *operational stats*.

If you're interested in the state of the physical structures, you'll look at the *physical stats*.

Once you're sure forwarded records are actually causing you a real performance problem, you'll fix them by not using heaps, rebuilding heaps, or changing table structure or queries so that fewer updates result in rows being forwarded.